# Range variable (re)assignment

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a range which is checked:

```
Dim myrange
myrange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

I want to get the range of row +1

```
 myrange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0)
```

But

```
 myrange =myrange.Offset(1, 0)
```

throw an error 424 object required

---

I also tried to define my variable

```
 Dim myrange As Range
```

But then at assignment it throws error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim myrange
myrange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

In the above `myrange` is declared as a variant, not a range. When you assign it `Worksheets(1).Range("A1")`, you are assigning the cell's value, not setting a range object. The following corrects it.

```
Dim myrange as range
SET myrange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

You can Offset from a range object but not a range's value. Once `myrange` is `Set`, the following should work.

```
Set myrange = myrange.Offset(1, 0)
```

`myrange` is now Set to `Worksheets(1).Range("A2")`. This can be double-checked with,

```
Debug.Print myrange.Address(0, 0, external:=true)
```